# Keeping a physicsBody in the middle of the SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I wasn't sure how to ask this question, but I have  a SKSpriteNode in my SKScene. I want it to be in the middle of the y axis, but on a swipe (up/down) to have gravity affect it until it returned back to the middle of the y axis.

Example set up:
1- SKSpriteNode in its default position (doesn't really matter where on x axis, but in the middle of y axis)
2- User swipes up
3- SKSpriteNode gets affected by a `applyImpulse()` in +y OR -y direction
4- Gravity affects SKSpriteNote in -y OR +y (respectively) direction
5- SKSpriteNode moves back to its default position (because of gravity)

How would I perform this?
Things I've tried:
- radialGravityField (wasn't performing as I expected)
- linearGravityFieldWithVector (I kind of failed with this)
- creating 2 rectangles with different gravities (which failed miserably)
- checking if SKSpriteNode y position is < or > than the middle of the screen depending on if the swipe was up or down, and if it was, reset the position. Checking in `didSimulatePhysics`. This didn't work, from what I could tell, it would reset the position, but when debugging, even after the reset the SKSpriteNode wasn't in the middle of the y Axis

Let me know if you require my code, but all I'm looking for is a method of doing this

Thanks :)

### Edit

Here is the code I am using for checking if the sprite position is < or > than the middle of the y Axis

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//set the players default position
playerDefaultPosition = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.2, y: self.size.height / 2)


//background
backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

//world physics
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

//create player
playerNode.position = playerDefaultPosition
playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: playerNode.size)
playerNode.physicsBody?.mass = 300
playerNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

addChild(playerNode)


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let yTouch = touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y {
        self.touches.append(yTouch)
        startTime = NSDate()

        }
    }

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let yTouch = touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y {
        self.touches.append(yTouch)

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let yTouch = touches.first?.locationInNode(self).y {
        endTime = NSDate()
        self.touches.append(yTouch)
        if !self.touches.isEmpty {
            let velocity = getVelocity(self.touches, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
            movePlayer(velocity)

        }


    }

func getVelocity(touchArray: [CGFloat], startTime: NSDate, endTime: NSDate) -> CGFloat {
    var v: CGFloat = 0
    if !touchArray.isEmpty {

        //get velocity from v = d/t
        let t = CGFloat(endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime))
        let d = touchArray.last! - touchArray.first!
        v = d / t
    }

    return v

}

func movePlayer(v: CGFloat) {
    let vector = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: v * 30)

    if vector.dy > 0 {
        //player going in +y direction
        swipedUp = true
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -10)
    } else {
        //player going in -y direction
        swipedUp = false
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 10)
    }

    playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)


}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    if playerNode.position.y < (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 1 && swipedUp || playerNode.position.y > (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 + 1 && !swipedUp {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
        print("gravity set to 0")
        playerNode.position = playerDefaultPosition

    }

}
```

After debugging more, seems that after it sets the `playerNode.position = playerDefaultPosition`, the next frame's `playerNode.position.y < (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 1 && swipedUp` is still true

### Edit 2

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) I implemented every function called during a frame and checked the position `playerNode.position.y` during each function call, and it seems that something happens when the SKScene simulates physics that makes the playerNode move from its default position to a different one.

Comment: maybe give it a little more error then just -1 try -10 or something.

Comment: @Steve No luck. I changed `(self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 1` to `(self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 10` to exaggerate anything happening, and I can see that the node is appearing I'm gessing at  `(self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 10` then goes back to `defaultPlayerPosition` and so on.

Comment: maybe try giving it an impulse with vector(0,0)?  Sorry I don't have xCode in front of me right now to try anything.

Comment: That's fine, I appreciate your help. I tried setting the applyImpulse to (0,0) but no luck. Will continue trying to find something now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve was on the right track when he said to `applyImpulse()` in `didSimulatePhysics()`. Since the object still had a force acting on it (due to it falling), I had to remove it.
You can either do this by finding the force it has coming down (which is more code than necessary for me) or I could just make it `.dynamic = false` and reenable it when I need it to be.

Here's what I have now:

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    print(playerNode.position.y)
    if playerNode.position.y < (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 10 && swipedUp || playerNode.position.y > (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 + 10 && !swipedUp {
        //turn off all forces on the Node    
        playerNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        playerNode.position = playerDefaultPosition
    }

}
```

Comment: glad you found it.  I knew it had to be related to something like that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just check for node's y position and when node's y < frame.middleY (or > ) turn off gravity for that node. Turn on back after swipe.

Comment: forgot that I had tried that, edited question. For some reason it would reset the position, but on the next frame the SKSpriteNode was moved.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the Impulse vector back to 0 in the Y direction

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    if playerNode.position.y < (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 - 1 && swipedUp || playerNode.position.y > (self.view?.frame.height)! / 2 + 1 && !swipedUp {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        print("gravity set to 0")
        let vector = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
        playerNode.position = playerDefaultPosition


    }

}
```

Comment: tried that as well. See edited post for info about frame data